# How to generate `c('q01','q02','q03','q04',...'q99')`?

Tags: r

I tried:

```
> c(paste('q', formatC(seq(1,99,1),width=2, flag="0"), sep='',collapse=","))
[1] "q01,q02,q03,q04,q05,q06,q07,q08,q09,q10,q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16,q17,q18,q19,q20,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25,q26,q27,q28,q29,q30,q31,q32,q33,q34,q35,q36,q37,q38,q39,q40,q41,q42,q43,q44,q45,q46,q47,q48,q49,q50,q51,q52,q53,q54,q55,q56,q57,q58,q59,q60,q61,q62,q63,q64,q65,q66,q67,q68,q69,q70,q71,q72,q73,q74,q75,q76,q77,q78,q79,q80,q81,q82,q83,q84,q85,q86,q87,q88,q89,q90,q91,q92,q93,q94,q95,q96,q97,q98,q99"
```

But I want `'q01','q02','q03'...'q99'`,how to do it?

Comment: don't use the `collapse` argument...Try `c(paste('q', formatC(seq(1, 99, 1), width = 2, flag = "0"), sep = ''))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use sprintf:

```
sprintf("q%02d", 1:99)
```

Comment: can I `c(sprintf("q%02d", 1:99))`?

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

You can try the following code

```
paste0("'", paste('q', formatC(1:99, width = 2, flag = "0"), sep = '', collapse = "','"), "'")
```

Output

```
# 'q01','q02','q03','q04','q05','q06','q07','q08','q09','q10','q11', ...
```

Comment: without `,`,I want `'q01','q02','q03'...`

Comment: @kittygirl I've updated my answer, please check it out